# Questions on the elementary excitations in the resonating-valence-bond(RVB) states?

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, topological-order, anyons, quasiparticles

It is known that the RVB states can support spin-charge separations and its elementary excitations are spinons and holons. But it seems that there are some different possibilities for the nature of the statistics of the spinons and holons. Specifically, (1) spinons are *fermions* while holons are *bosons*([Kivelson et al](http://prb.aps.org/abstract/PRB/v35/i16/p8865_1));(2)spinons are *bosons* while holons are *fermions*([Read et al](http://prb.aps.org/abstract/PRB/v40/i10/p7133_1));(3)spinons and holons are both *semions* obeying fractional statistics([Laughlin et al](http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v59/i18/p2095_1)).

Do we now have a commonly accepted view for one of the above three possibilities? Or do the quasiparticle statistics depend on the details(e.g. which kind) of the RVB wave functions?

Furthermore, assume RVB states as the ground-states of the antiferromagnetic Heisenberg model, and when we use $t-J$ model to study the **lightly doped** Mott insulator, for the possibility (1), it's reasonable to adopt **slave-boson** formalism, while for the possibility (2), it's reasonable to adopt **slave-fermion** formalism, right? But for the possibility (3), what kind of **slave-particle** formalism we should adopt? This part may be related to my previous [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63073/whatre-the-relations-and-differences-between-slave-fermion-and-slave-boson-form).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See articles: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/what-is-a-resonating-valence-bond-rvb-state,
http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29360/is-resonating-valence-bond-rvb-states-long-range-entangled, and
http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57448/whats-vison-in-z2-resonating-valence-bond-rvb-state

Comment: Here is a very nice answer by Prof.Wen on overflow: http://www.physicsoverflow.org/6327/questions-elementary-excitations-resonating-valence-states?show=13169#a13169